# Proving that a compact Hausdorff space is a Baire space.

Tags: general-topology, compactness

This is exercise 27.5 in Munkres:

> Let $X$ be a compact Hausdorff space; Let $\{A_n\}$ be a countable collection of closed sets of $X$. Show that if each set $A_n$ has empty interior in $X$, then the union $\bigcup A_n$ has empty interior in $X$. [*Hint:* Imitate the proof of Theorem 27.7.]

Here is Theorem 27.7:

> Let $X$ be a nonempty compact Hausdorff space. If $X$ has no isolated points, then $X$ is uncountable.

The proof of Theorem 27.7 boils down to this:

1. Show that given any nonempty open set $U$ of $X$ and any $x\in X$, there exists a nonempty open set $V$ contained in $U$ such that $x\notin\overline V$.
2. Given $f:\mathbb Z_+\to X$, use 1. to construct a sequence of points $x_n$ all distinct from $x$. It follows that $f$ is not surjective, and hence $X$ is uncountable.

I don't see any relation between the exercise and the proof of the theorem. The theorem constructs a sequence of points, while the exercise requires me to show that a set has empty interior. Any hints on how to relate these two would be greatly appreciated (I'd like to complete the proof myself).

Comment: To prove the exercise, you wish to show that given any non-empty open set $U$, $U$ contains a point outside $\bigcup A_n$. In the same manner as the proof of theorem 27.7, you wish to construct a decreasing sequence of open sets which avoid $A_n$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose that $O \subseteq \bigcup_n A_n$ is non-empty open.

$A_1$ has empty interior and is closed, so there is some $O_1$ non-empty open with $\overline{O_1} \subseteq O$ such that $O_1 \cap A_1 = \emptyset$.

$A_1 \cup A_2$ also has empty interior and is still closed, so there is some non-empty open $O_2$ such that $O_2 \subseteq \overline{O_2} \subseteq O_1$ and $O_2 \cap (A_1 \cup A_2)=\emptyset$.

Continue finding $O_n$ this way and note that $\bigcap_n \overline{O_n}$ is non-empty by compactness and see what contradiction you find.

With a minor adaptation at the start, this also works for locally compact Hausdorff spaces.

The common theme with the older proof is the decreasing open sets intersecting to achieve a "countable goal" when finite goals are achievable.

Comment: Thanks, but where exactly did you use Hausdorffness?

Comment: I think I see it: Since $\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty \overline O_n$ and $\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty A_n$ are disjoint, there exist points $x\in\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty \overline O_n$ and $y\in\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty A_n$ with disjoint neighborhoods $U$ and $V$. But this means that $V\subset \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty A_n$, contradicting the assumption that $\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty A_n$ has empty interior. Is that correct?

Comment: @Math1000 I use it when I apply regularity in the shrinking (closures) of open sets. The contradiction lies in the fact that $x\in U$ but $x\notin \bigcup_n A_n$ despite the initial assumptions of non-empty interior (which gave us $O$ in the first place).

Comment: I didn't see a $U$ in your post. Are you referring to the $U$ in my comment?

Comment: And as for "regularity," $X$ is regular because it is compact Hausdorff, correct? Sorry, I have not yet studied regular spaces.

Comment: @Math1000 I meant the $O$ from my post. And indeed a compact Hausdorff space is regular is used.

Comment: Thank you, I have accepted your answer.

Answer (score 0):

The Baire category theorem is theorem 48.2 in Munkres. The proof of the theorem, and so also a proof adequate for this problem, is found there (page 296 in my edition). I used the proof outlined there to construct my proof for problem 27.5.

There is a line of the proof which states

> Regularity of $X,$ along with the fact that $A_1$ is closed, enables us to choose a neighborhood $U_1$ of $y$ such that $$\bar{U}_1 \cap A_n = \emptyset,$$ $$\bar{U}_1 \subset U_0.$$

The ideas used in proving theorem 27.7 are needed to justify this step, which justification Munkres leaves out in proving 48.2. Step one of the proof of 27.7 says

> We show first that given any nonempty open set $U$ of $X$ and any point $x$ of $X,$ there exists a nonempty open set $V$ contained in $U$ such that $x \notin \bar{V}.$

For problem 27.5, you need to show that for all $n$ there exists a nonempty open set $U_n$ contained in $U_{n-1}$ such that $A_n \cap \bar{U}_n = \emptyset.$ This is the similarity with theorem 27.7.

Bellow is my proof, which I believe to be correct. Perhaps it will clarify what I mean.

> Let $X \neq \emptyset$ be a compact Hausdorff space and let $\{A_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N} }$ be a countable collection of closed subsets of $X.$ Assume that $\text{Int} A_i = \emptyset \,\forall\, i.$ Let $U_0$ be any nonempty open set. Then $U_0 \not\subset A_1,$ so we can choose some $y_1 \in U_0 \setminus A_1.$ Since $X$ is Hausdorff and $A_1$ is compact, by lemma 26.4 we can choose neighborhoods $U_1$ of $y_1$ and $V_1$ containing $A_1$ such that  $U_1 \subset U_0$ and $U_1 \cap A_1 = U_1 \cap V_1 = \emptyset \implies \bar{U}_1 \cap A_1 = \emptyset.$ Since $U_{n-1} \not\subset A_n,$ we can follow a similar procedure for $n>1$ to choose $y_n \in U_{n-1} \setminus A_n$ and then choose an open set $U_n$ around $y_n$ such that $\bar{U}_n \cap A_n = \emptyset$ and $\bar{U}_n \subset U_{n-1}.$ Since $X$ is compact, by theorem 26.9 $\exists\, z \in \bigcap_{n \in \mathbb{N} } \bar{U}_n.$ This $z$ is not contained in any of the $ A_n,$ so $z \notin \bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N} }A_n.$
>
> This shows that every open set must contain an element not contained in $\bigcup_{n \in \text{N} } A_n.$ It follows that $\bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N} } A_n$ can contain no open sets.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is based on Henno Brandsma's answer, which had a few gaps that have not all been addressed in comments. I am merely filling those gaps.

Suppose that $O \subset \bigcup_n A_n$ is non-empty open.

Let $O_1 = O \cap (X - A_1)$. Since $A_1$ has empty interior, $O_1$ is not empty. Since $A_1$ and is closed and $O$ is open, $O_1$ is open.

Pick any point $x_1 \in O_1$. $x_1$ is not in $X - O_1$, which is closed and hence compact. So Lemma 26.4 tells us that there exist disjoint open sets $U_1$ and $V_1$ of $X$ containing $x_1$ and $X - O_1$, respectively. Now it is easy to show that $U_1 \subset \bar{U_1} \subset O_1 \subset O$. Obviously $U_1 \cap A_1 = \emptyset$.

$A_1 \cup A_2$ also has empty interior and is still closed, so there is some non-empty open $U_2$ such that $U_2 \subset \bar{U_2} \subset U_1$ and $U_2 \cap (A_1 \cup A_2)=\emptyset$.

Continue finding $U_n$ this way and note that $\bigcap_n \bar{U_n}$ is non-empty by compactness. Let $x_0 \in \bigcap_n \bar{U_n}$. $x_0$ must be in $O$ by construction. Yet it cannot be in any $A_n$. This a contradiction.